# Is it possible to use import for development and react.lazy for production in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lazy-loading

There's a question: Is it possible to use import for development and react.lazy for production?

Why I need this: There's a project including highchart charts. The page can be "broken" by adding or removing files in a folder and I have to reload the page to watch the result again. But react.lazy helps to load the page faster so I need this option too.

That's why I would like to divide them into 2 parts: real imports for dev mode and lazy loading for prod mode.